# I have a problem with some Minecraft hoppers!

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]I have a problem with some Minecraft hoppers. I have red stone in front of them the power a dispenser going into them. They are all facing to the right. The middle isn't working for some reason. It's an automatic farm btw. Help! This took me three hours to [image: perfect]

Comment: Can you throw in some screenshots for us?

Comment: I would but I'm not entirley sure how to

Comment: Ok I figured out to upload a screenshot

Comment: Doesn't redstone power going to a hopper stop it from working?

Comment: @DanielG Yes that's right. Which means the red stone pulse has to be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, an active redstone line will prevent the hopper from working. This was added for the purpose of turning on and off the hopper line. I would find a way to reroute the redstone line so that it isn't near the hoppers.

Answer (score 0):

From the image, I can see a couple flaws.

The redstone line has to be moved elsewhere as to not interfere with the hoppers; and the droppers need a better clocking-system to keep all of them in sync.

My example of this:
[image: Efficient Dropper System]
[image: Efficient Dropper System]

And the best thing about my design (from what I've seen concerning copying/forking of designs) is that the circuit can be stacked on multiple layers.
So it can reach the skies!
[image: Stacking on Multiple Layers]
[image: Stacking on Multiple Layers]

Just attach a hopper line to the top dropper (don't worry, the circuitry will be low enough so any signals will not interfere) and you'll be on your way! 
This circuit is specialised so that the droppers automatically output their items into their above-droppers and-so-on when items are input into the bottom dropper. (Or any other dropper in an interval of 3!)

(Note: You'll need the Newest Version of Minecraft: PE to access all features of this design, which you'll 99.99%-most likely have anyway due to automatic-updates. Just a warning though.)

Make the most of this design, share with friends, family, etc.! Thanks for reading!